# select last rows based on a condition and store value into the variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having following dataframe in pandas in python 3.7 and reading excel. e.g. of a dataframe is

```
data = {'s':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
        'cp':['C','P','C','C','C','P'],
        'st':[300,300,300,300,310,310],
         'qty':[3000,3000,3000,6000,9000,3000],
         'p':[16,15,14,10,8,12]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    s   cp  st  qty p
0   a   C   300 3000    16
1   a   P   300 3000    15
2   a   C   300 3000    14
3   a   C   300 6000    10
4   b   C   310 9000    8
5   b   P   310 3000    12
```

I want to store a last value of cp i.e. "C" and "P" of column "cp" of group by column "s" of values column "p" into variables for e.g. a and b variables for condition "s" = a are last value of cp where cp == "C" is 10 and for cp == "P" is 15 then variable "a" should have value 10 and variable "b" should have value of 15.

For "s" == "b" then values of a = 8 and b = 12

I am reading s values from another excel/csv file using pandas.

Can you pl help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If always exist at least one `C` and one `P` is convert `p` column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, swap ordering with slicing `[::-1]` and get last matched `C` or `P` per condition:

```
a = df.set_index('p')['cp'].eq('C')[::-1].idxmax()
print (a)
8
b = df.set_index('p')['cp'].eq('P')[::-1].idxmax()
print (b)
12
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['s','cp'], keep='last')[['s','cp','p']]
print (df1)
   s cp   p
1  a  P  15
3  a  C  10
4  b  C   8
5  b  P  12
```

General solution with specify values for `s` and `cp`:

```
a = next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('C') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist')
print (a)
10
b = next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('P')& df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist')
print (b)
15

a = next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('C') & df['s'].eq('b'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist')
print (a)
8
b = next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('P')& df['s'].eq('b'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist')
print (b)
12
```

**Details**:

First filter by both conditions with bitwise `AND` by `&` and `loc` for filter column `p`:

```
print (df.loc[df['cp'].eq('C') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'])
0    16
2    14
3    10
Name: p, dtype: int64
```

Then convert to numpy array and slicing with `[::-1]`:

```
print (df.loc[df['cp'].eq('C') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1])
[10 14 16]
```

And last get first value of array:

```
print (next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('C') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist'))
10
```

---

If test not exist values, here `AAA`:

```
print (df.loc[df['cp'].eq('AAAA') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'])
Series([], Name: p, dtype: int64)

print (df.loc[df['cp'].eq('AAAA') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1])
[]

print (next(iter(df.loc[df['cp'].eq('AAA') & df['s'].eq('a'), 'p'].values[::-1]), 'no exist'))
no exist
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry my initial question does not mentioned it should be based on value of column "s" where I am reading value of "s" from another file using pandas I am getting s value for eg. I want something a=10 where s="a" and "cp" =="C" and b = 15 where s="a" and "cp" == "P" and next time a=8 and b=12 where s=="b" and "cp"=="C" and "cp" == "P" respectively.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael can you pl explain what does [::-1] is doing ?

Comment: @Parag - It swap values - first to last, maybe help `s = pd.Series([3,6,1])
print (s[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jezral

I got an answer from your query

```
df[(df.s == "a")].set_index('p')['cp'].eq('C')[::-1].idxmax()
df[(df.s == "a")].set_index('p')['cp'].eq('P')[::-1].idxmax()
```

Will you pl explain what does it [::-1] is doing and set_index ?